# Request method 'GET' not supported in Dockerized SpringBoot REST api

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jmeter

I have a small spring application as shown below:

```
package com.example.demo.api;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping("api/factorial")
@RestController
public class TestApi {

    @GetMapping
    public long factorial(){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int i;
        double fact=1;
        int number=50;//It is the number to calculate factorial
        for(i=1;i<=number;i++){
            fact=fact*i;
            System.out.println("Factorial of "+i+" is: "+fact);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return (endTime - startTime);
    }
}
```

I have generated a jar of this application and dockerized it as shown below:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD  ./demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/factorial/
WORKDIR /usr/src/factorial
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I then run the below command run the docker container

```
docker run --rm --name factorialContainer -p 8080:8080 -e JAVA_OPTIONS="$(cat jvmFlags.txt)" suleka96/factorial:latest
```

Then I am trying to make a HTTP request to the REST endpoint using JMeter as shown below
[image]

The problem is that when i do this I get an error saying:

> org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

However, when I run the spring application locally (without dockerizing it)
and send a request from JMeter, the request successfully gets sent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm familirazed with Springboot but it looks like your app is listening on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0` when it runs inside docker

Comment: what happens when you try from your browser? same error?

Comment: it works for me, have you got anything weird in the jvmFlags,txt?Also what happens if you make the request to the container using `curl -v` instead of jmeter, there might be a clue in the request / response headers

Comment: @andre The browser gives the same error

Comment: @stringy jvmFlag.txt only has a list of jvm flags like: -XX:+UseSerialGC. The curl request gives me the same error: {"timestamp":"2020-02-04T05:01:59.029+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/api/factorial"}

Comment: @lleon docker ps shows that it is listening on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Your application is deployed in docker, so it is virtual machine. That is another host with it's own ip address. But you are trying to send GET request to localhost. You should get your docker ip.
Type this to get ip in Mac OS

host> docker-machine ip default

Visit that page https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/ there's a section about mac os deployment in that knowledge base

Comment: that's not accurate, since she is mapping the port, the container will be visible as a service running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this has got to be in the logs.

Here's my setup, I changed the controller so it would return json rather than the long primitive:

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("api/factorial")
@RestController
public class TestApi {

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Long> factorial(){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int i;
        double fact=1;
        int number=50;//It is the number to calculate factorial
        for(i=1;i<=number;i++){
            fact=fact*i;
            System.out.println("Factorial of "+i+" is: "+fact);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        Map<String, Long> res = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        res.put("time_in_nanos", (endTime - startTime));
        return res;
    }
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demo")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom

```
ml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <springboot.version>2.0.8.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Springboot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Docker command line

```
docker run --rm --name apiTest -p 8080:8080  321225ee07bb
```

I used your Dockerfile pretty much as is

Log out put from the container:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.8.RELEASE)

2020-02-04 22:55:03.774  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.api.Application         : Starting Application on 33f1f71d079b with PID 1 (/usr/src/factorial/demo-1.0.jar started by root in /usr/src/factorial)
2020-02-04 22:55:03.796  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.api.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-04 22:55:04.076  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2f410acf: startup date [Tue Feb 04 22:55:04 GMT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-02-04 22:55:08.891  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-04 22:55:09.002  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-04 22:55:09.004  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
2020-02-04 22:55:09.055  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2020-02-04 22:55:09.305  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-04 22:55:09.307  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5236 ms
2020-02-04 22:55:10.617  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.626  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.636  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.641  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.645  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.647  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2020-02-04 22:55:10.649  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2020-02-04 22:55:11.290  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-02-04 22:55:11.658  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2f410acf: startup date [Tue Feb 04 22:55:04 GMT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-02-04 22:55:11.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/factorial],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long> com.example.demo.api.TestApi.factorial()
2020-02-04 22:55:11.879  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2020-02-04 22:55:11.880  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2020-02-04 22:55:11.960  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-02-04 22:55:11.962  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-02-04 22:55:12.745  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-02-04 22:55:12.787  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2020-02-04 22:55:12.792  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2020-02-04 22:55:12.796  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2020-02-04 22:55:12.950  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2020-02-04 22:55:13.124  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-04 22:55:13.135  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.api.Application         : Started Application in 10.73 seconds (JVM running for 12.233)
```

What I'd look for is the mapping of the GET request like this:

```
2020-02-04 22:55:11.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/factorial],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long> com.example.demo.api.TestApi.factorial()
```